# SQL how to display multiple column data concatenated with a string as one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table student_data below. I want use MySQL to display this data, without modifying it, with the addition of a column containing data from each of the columns concatenated with a string.

```
Age  Name  Grade
11   Matt  94
12   Josh  80
13   May   95
```

should turn into:

```
Result                 Age  Name  Grade
Matt (11) scored 94    11   Matt  94
Josh (12) scored 80    12   Josh  80
May (13) scored 95     13   May   95
```

without modifying the original table.

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(field_1, ' (', field_2, ') scored', field_3) AS concat_field, field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM .... `

Comment: If you can compromise on the wording a little, this can get even shorter `select *, concat_ws(' ',name,'Age',age,'Scored',grade)`

Answer (score 4):

This is basically filling in a template.  I like to use `replace()` for this purpose (I'm sure someone else will answer with the `concat()` method):

```
select replace(replace(replace('[name] ([age]) scored [grade]',
                               '[name]', name
                              ), '[age]', age
                      ), '[grade]', grade
              ) as result,
        t.*
from t;
```

Despite the indentation issues, I like this method because the template string is obvious and easy to change.

Comment: This is elegant --  But unnecessarily complicated given `CONCAT` -- But you already knew that ;)

Comment: Yes, I would have suggested `CONCAT`. But the template thing a nice idea. I wish there was a multi_replace function, so we wouldn't have to nest several replaces, though.

Comment: Congratulations on the 1000K!

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity --  Athough I like Gordon's answer.

I'd use `CONCAT();`

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' (', age, ') scored ', score) AS result, age, name, score 
    FROM your_table;
```